# Differentiating message event type while catching payload on facebook webhook

Tags: facebook, menu, bots, messenger, payload

I am creating a facebook chatbot and i can get different kinds of JSON format for persistent menu, quick replies and simple messages. Is there any way that i can differentiate what functionality (i.e. either persistent menu, quick reply, button template) is triggering the webhook call?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of actions, that can trigger webhook by the date 10th Sept 2017. You can differentiate the calls by parsing JSON format. Each one has its own structure encapsulated with a general structure.

- Message
- Message Delivered
- Message Read
- Message Echo
- Postback
- Plugin Opt-in
- Referral
- Payment (beta)
- Checkout Update (beta)
- Pre-Checkout (beta)
- Account Linking Event
- Policy Enforcement Event
- App Roles (beta)
- Standby (beta)
- Pass Thread Control (beta)
- Take Thread Control (beta)

To find out more check out the related dev docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference

Comment: Hi mustafaturan,
Thanks for the information.
But the problem i am facing is - everything is getting replied on the same webhook by facebook. So, is there any way i can differentiate between these actions. Are there any 'keys' sent by facebook, that we can use to differentiate between these actions?
I am looking at the JSON formats and i can see 'Payload' which are custom defined. So, i have to find individual payload and then define what action is triggering that payload. Would have been great if we can filter action, then handle the payload accordingly.

Comment: Yes, each action type that I specified above is coming with its own special json payload. You can read the docs to see sample payloads how they are different each other. 

For example, Facebook sends webhook in this format when the user reads messages:

...
   "read":{
      "watermark":1458668856253,
      "seq":38
   }
..

and this one when message delivers:

...
   "delivery":{
      "mids":[
         "mid.1458668856218:ed81099e15d3f4f233"
      ],
      "watermark":1458668856253,
      "seq":37
   }
...

as seen in samples read/delivery keys are different